# How to prove that the subrings of the rational numbers are noetherian?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I have managed to prove that the aforementioned subrings are in bijection with the subsets of the primes, however, I haven't been able to prove that they are all noetherian. I need help.

Comment: Try to prove that they are all PIDs.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework question, and is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 9):

I will break this up into two steps, each of which is a standard exercise:

1) Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain with fraction field $K$.  Every **overring** of $R$ -- i.e., every ring $S$ with $R \subset S \subset K$ -- is the localization of $R$ at a multiplicative subset.

2) If $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $S$ is a multiplicative subset, then the localization $S^{-1} R$ is a Noetherian ring.